# How do I know Splunk REST API Base URL?

Tags: rest, splunk

We have Splunk deployed in https://splunkit.corp.company.com (url modified).

and able to access Splunk Web home page on https://splunkit.corp.company.com/en-US/app/launcher/home (url modified).

I am building a dashboard application which uses the JSON data provided by Splunk REST services.

I have gone through the [link](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTUM/RESTusing) and rest end points as [here](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.3/RESTTUT/RESTsearches).

From above links I got know

> I need to make post request to services/auth/login with username and password. This returns session key which will be used in further API calls.
>
> Have to make post request to services/search/jobs to create a search. This returns search id.
>
> I need to check services/search/jobs/ for search complete.
>
> If search complete Then I can retrieve results using services/search/jobs//results.

The problem here I facing is I don't know whats the base URL. I tried constructing https://splunkit.corp.company.com/en-US/services/auth/login and etc but not working.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same question earlier. Well here is an workaround to find out the `REST API Base URL`. I found this solution by accident in fact.

- In the Firefox browser, open the `Web Developer` / `Network` tool, to inspect the URLs between your local computer and the Splunk server
- Logon to the Splunk via Web Interface
- We assume you had finished a search beforehand, so there should be an `Job` stored on the Server already. Then, we click the `Activity` / `Jobs` link at the right top location of the window
- There will be a list of jobs listed. Choose any job, click the `Job` / `Delete Job` button, then the Job search result will be deleted.
- In the `Web Developer` tool, inspect the URL when deleting the job

For me, I got an URL looks like:

> https://the-company-splunk-server.com/en-US/splunkd/__raw/services/search/jobs/scheduler_search_RMD554b7a649e94cdf69_at_1526886000_58534?output_mode=json

The top *secret* is: **the URL before `/services/` is the `REST API Base URL`**. In this case, the base URL is:

> https://the-company-splunk-server.com/en-US/splunkd/__raw/services/

### Test the Base URl

We can try this `Base URL` for login with `CURL`:

> curl --insecure https://the-company-splunk-server.com/en-US/splunkd/__raw/services/auth/login -d username=your-user -d password=your-password

We got the following result:

```
<response>
<sessionKey>kq6gkXO_dFcJzJG2XpwZs1IwfhH8MkkYDaBsZrPxZh8</sessionKey>
</response>
```

So the test is succeed. We have proven the base URL works.

Good luck.

Comment: I have the link in the format of https://splunk-company.name , and this approach is not working. Am I getting the url not correctly_